# Elementary set proof

Tags: probability

On a statistics trial exam I encountered the following proof I was supposed to give but I have no idea how to start with this proof and solve it:

$P(A\cap B)$ $\geq$ $1 - P(A') - P(B')$ where $A'$ is the complement of A

If anyone could help me, that would be great!

Comment: Rewrite it so that the probabilities are all on the same side. What can you say about the union of the sets?

Comment: Then you get $P(A\cap B) + P(A') + P(B')$ $\geq 1$ right?

Comment: Typo ;) @tomasz

Comment: @SjoerdSmaal Right. Now, what about the union?

Comment: Which union, do you mean $P(A') + P(B')$ ?

Comment: No, $(A\cap B) \cup A' \cup B'$.

Comment: $\forall$ $x$, $x\in A$ and $B$, and/or $x\in A'$, and/or $x\in B'$, is that true?

Comment: "or" is the correct term you want for union. Think about it: $\forall x, [(x\in A$ and $x\in B)$ or $(x \notin A)$ or $(x\notin B)]$

Comment: Aah, i see it, thank you @amWhy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, split up the sample space: $S=(A\cap B) \cup A^C \cup B^C\\ \iff P(S)=P(A\cap B) + P(A^C) + P(B^C) - P(A^C \cap B^C)\\ \iff P(A\cap B) = \underbrace{P(S)}_{=1} - P(A^C) - P(B^C) + P(A^C \cap B^C).\\ \text{Now since } P(A^C \cap B^C) \geq 0,\\ P(A\cap B) \geq 1 - P(A^C) - P(B^C).$

Answer (score 3):

Note that $$P(A\cap B) \geq 1 - P(A') - P(B') \iff P(A\cap B) + P(A') + P(B') \geq 1$$

(We didn't change the inequality at all!)

Now, what is the union of the sets?: How does this relate to $(A\cap B) \cup A' \cup B'\;?$

Further clarification: Note: we can use Demorgan's: $$A' \cup B' = (A \cap B)'$$ So you have that $$(A\cap B) \cup (A' \cup B') = (A\cap B) \cup (A \cap B)'$$

Which means: "$x \in (A\cap B)$ or $x \in (A\cap B)'$."

Or, $$x \in (A\cap B)\;\;\text{OR}\;\;x \notin (A\cap B)$$

What is the probability that $x \in (A\cap B)$ or $x \notin (A\cap B)$

That's always true, yes?

Comment: Mmm, I see what you are doing, so $x\in A$ and $B$ and/or $x\in A' $ and/or $x\in B'$ right

Answer (score 2):

DeMorgan's Laws tell us that $$(A\cap B)'=A'\cup B',$$ and since $$P\bigl((A\cap B)'\bigr)=P(A'\cup B')=P(A')+P(B')-P(A'\cap B'),$$ then $$P\bigl((A\cap B)'\bigr)\le P(A')+P(B').$$ Now, how are $P(A\cap B)$ and $P\bigl((A\cap B)'\bigr)$ related?

Comment: Perfect answer! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
P(A\cup  B) &= P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)\\
P(A\cap B)&=-P(A\cup  B)+  P(A)+P(B)\\
P(A\cap B)&=-P(A\cup  B)+  1-P(A')+1-P(B')\\
P(A\cap B)&=1-P(A\cup  B)+  1-P(A')-P(B')\\
P(A\cap B)&=P((A\cup  B)')+  1-P(A')-P(B')\\
P(A\cap B)&\geq  1-P(A')-P(B') \qquad [P(\bullet)\geq 0]\\ 
\end{align}